# how to view http post result in a browser using java

Tags: java

I would like to view the result of an http post in a browser but it is not working i've tried to use PrintWriter but still not showing the result in a browser
the system.out.println in the code is showing the result in the console i want the same result in the browser bellow is my code, i'm using netbeans and JSF

public void sendRequest()  throws Exception{

```
                             String url = "http://34.198.239.23:3000/transactions";

    DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);

    // add header
    post.setHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");


    List<NameValuePair> urlParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

    urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("secret_key", "afec6d477b7f4d91e177b707a4c58bf55b921926"));
    urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("public_key", "c0b7372d96633b6414a7e7b7a53c996d3a63acfb"));
    urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("product_name", "amagati"));
    urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("product_unitid", "id"));
    urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("product_type", "food"));
            urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("error_url","vugapay.com/terms"));
             urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("success_url","vugapay.com"));
              urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("amount","5000"));
              urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("extra_field","hello"));
               urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("currency","usd"));
    post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(urlParameters));

    HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);



    System.out.println("\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + url);
    System.out.println("Post parameters : " + post.getEntity());
    System.out.println("Response Code : " +
                                response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());

    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

    StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
    String line = "";
    while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {

        result.append(line);
    }
       // i tried to use this to view this so that it can appear in the browser
        PrintWriter printwriter=response.getAllHeaders();
        printwriter.print(result.toString());

    System.out.println(result.toString());
            System.out.println("Done!");




    }
```

Comment: You can use Fiddler to do this (google search fiddler and install it on your computer). It will show you all http requests and responses. No code modification necessary.

Answer (score 0):

System.out.println method is to print into console, So you need to use HttpServletResponse to print your text into browser

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
// your code here
response.setContentType("text/html");
response.getWriter().print(result); 
}
```

Comment: Thaks for your quick response i finally found the answer i just added redirection to the url link and it led me to another page with all my request visible